# jQuery tooltip won't show on button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am currently trying out the jQuery UI Tooltip plugin using jQuery v1.7.2 and jQuery UI v1.10.4

I've reproduced a barebone setup of the problem I am facing here: http://jsfiddle.net/bCN4X/1/

What I would want to obtain is that the table inside the hidden div is used as the button tooltip, and it should also be shown/hidden on click on the button.

I have tried binding some log function on the `create`, `open` and `close` events for the tooltip, however, while it seems that it is correctly created, it never shows up, not on hover nor on clicking.

I have already used the plugin, on some thumbnail images to show the full image, and that worked flawlessly, this should be a simple setup and yet I can't have it work properly.

How can I then make it work as intended? Do I need to change some of the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just posted the question and, fiddling around, I found the problem, so I am answering my own question for future reference, should any of you encounter the same problem.

The error was caused by the fact that the element had no `title` attribute, and this caused the tooltip not to trigger; adding a `title` to the button solved the problem.

I have updated my setup and now works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/bCN4X/2/

It looks like a bug to me, so I am going to report it to jQuery UI developers.